# How to reinstall windows 8 without losing my files and apps

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

My windows 8.1 installation on my hard drive is corrupt and my PC won't boot. Is there a way to reinstall windows 8.1 on my hard drive without losing my files and apps? I use an acer-E1 532p.

Comment: " Is there a way to reinstall windows 8.1 on my hard drive without losing my files and apps?" - This is only possible if you can boot into Windows.

Comment: Can i take out my hard drive, make it external and use another pc?

Comment: Check your manual for information on how/if it is possible to remove the drive from the system. If it is, it should be possible to attach it to another system.

Comment: @ebere Of course you can

Comment: I have removed the drive already and got a sata to usb converter to make the drive external. How do i now reinstall windows without loosing my apps and files

Comment: Preserving data files is easy - if you can find them all. Preserving most of the files that make up "apps" is relatively easy. But installing an app is more than just copying files to the hard drive. With a new (i.e. reinstall) of Windows you get a brand new registry, and an app's installer is typically the _only_ thing you have that knows how to put what the app needs in the registry. I wish every app included a "reinstall on current OS's drive" utility in its `\Program files` directory, but they don't. Moral: Keep all of your installation media and license keys forever.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a harddrive-USB adapter and copy all files to another drive and then reinstall Windows on the backed-up hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

The drives will be preserved, if you haven't deleted/formatted those partitions while re-installing the OS. And also, it will copy the older files in C drive to a folder name "Windows.old" in C:.  Please check only online for the tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of solutions, depending on hardware at hand:

- With a working laptop and a USB disk box: remove the disk, put it a USB disk box, connect to some other PC to copy files.
- With a working desktop and a SATA connector adapter (2.5" to 3.5"), or a working laptop that has a second HDD bay: remove the disk, connect on other computer, reboot to copy files
- With just an external HDD or USB key, boot a Linux LiveCD or Live USB on the troubled computer, access the disk and copy file to a connected HDD/USB key (which can be the one on which you booted the Linux, if big enough). Don't be shy, this isn't technically hard, booting a Linux LiveCD works exactly like Windows (even easier...). With some luck, booting a LiveCD may also be used to repair the Windows installation (restore some files) and avoid a complete re-install.
- With your bare hands: reinstall Windows and pray that it doesn't trash your files.